# live linked image in spreadsheet

Tags: image, live, google-sheets

I am sure this is a basic question but i am trying to create a project tracking document in google spreadsheets. The ideal scenario would be to have an image on our server that is used as a thumbnail in the spreadsheet. Then i would like to be able to overwrite that image and have it update on refresh in the spreadsheet.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in the scope of a Google Spreadsheet by creating your own [Spreadsheet Gadget](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96978).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="Hello World!" />
  <UserPref name="_table_query_url" display_name="Data source url" required="true"/>
  <Content type="html"><![CDATA[
    <img src="http://99designs.com/designs/447080~36d200d82d83d7b2e738cebd2a48de07180cef3a-original">
  ]]></Content>
</Module>
```

However, Gadgets will be [deprecated in early 2013](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2791335).